# Raspberry pi 3 Memory partition

Tags: video, partition, vlc

I have installed Raspbian stretch latest on my Rpi 3 B 
on a 8gb sdcard 
and I can't run any videos  or windows application through wine. 
It says 1G/3G partition is required and no video is played
only audio  but pi gets over heated when I attempted to play videos 
Any solutions to these problems

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. What do you mean by "over heated"? How does it show? Is there anything that works on your Pi at all? Feel free to edit the question.

Comment: Overheated - I can see a thermometer icon and even board emits lot of heat, And yes I can run most of the default softwares + play music just can't run video and windows software's through Wine  . All I need is some help on how to do 3G/1G user /kernel memory split